# Hibernate 6 Entity Error - Unable to determine JavaType to use : BasicValue([Column(ID)])

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```java
// Entity
@Id
private Long id;
```

In Oracle Database, column ID is of type NUMBER

I'm getting this error when I try to boot up my Spring Boot application Unable to determine JavaType to use : BasicValue([Column(ID)])

I tried including a couple annotations like
@GeneratedValue, @JavaType and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the mappings between Java Type and Oracle Data Type here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/gcmaz/

I imagine you will need to change your Java Type from Long to perhaps BigInteger based on the mappings guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue was in one of the relationships configured on the entity.